# Cannot be resolved or is not a field for SUPPORTED_ABIS,FLAVOR & VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-5.0-lollipop

I get the error **Cannot be resolved or is not a field**  for following codings

```
 Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS
 Build.FLAVOR
 Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP
```

- I have upgraded the latest SDK upto Lolipop
- I have tried restarting
  the Eclipse
- I have tried Cleaning and Building the project.
- I have even tried restarting the system.

But nothing works.

Comment: Both added in API level 21 so make sure you have selected 2 api for project and also in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: You have to compile with api 21.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This problem is due to not setting the right  **Build target** of your project

- Right click on your *project*
- Choose *properties*
- Choose *Android*
- Choose *Target* name whose **API level** is **21** or **above**.
- Press *Ok*

Comment: If I go to 21+, it doesn't recognize http!

Comment: @Ahmed - Can you explain "it doesn't recognize http" ?

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H Apparently HttpClient is not supported any more in sdk 23. So we have to use URLConnection or use a compat lib.

Comment: Ok .. Thanks for the info